# Need Persistent key value store which can be accessed via http

Tags: redis, key-value-store, leveldb, rocksdb

I am looking for a persistent key DB which can be accessed via HTTP. I need to use it for storing postman test script data. I have heard of rocksdb and leveldb, but I am not sure whether they can be accessed via HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leveldb and rocksdb don't have a network component.

I created a small python project that does expose a document datastore like API that you can query using REST. Have a look at it https://github.com/amirouche/deuspy. It rely on leveldb for persistence.

There is a python asyncio client. You can create a client on your own it's very easy.

To get started, you can simply do the following:

```
pip3 install deuspy
python3 -m deuspy.server
```

And then start querying.

Here is an example `curl`-based session:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:9990
{}
$ curl -X POST --data '{"héllo": "world"}' http://localhost:9990
3252169150753703489
$ $ curl -X GET http://localhost:9990/3252169150753703489
{"h\u00e9llo": "world"}
```

You can also filter documents. [Look at how is implemented the asyncio client](https://github.com/amirouche/deuspy/blob/master/deuspy/client.py#L48).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Webdis which provides HTTP REST API access to Redis key value store. Redis has very good performance and scalability.

Comment: But It is an in-memory key value store. What happens on unexpected shutdown.